# variable not incrementing

Tags: javascript, increment

```
var ro = 0;

function updatePR(sel){
    if(sel.value==1){
        $(".holder").append("<div id='simulador-"+ro+"'></div>");
        $("#simulador-"+ro).load("inv-imo.php .IM");
        ro=ro++;
    }else if(sel.value==2){
        $(".holder").append("<div id='simulador-"+ro+"'></div>");
        $("#simulador-"+ro).load("poupanca.php .SP");
        ro=ro++;
    }else if(sel.value==3){
        $(".holder").append();
    }
}
```

I have this code and I'm having trouble with the variable `ro`, which doesn't increment.

Everytime that I run the function, `ro` is always 0.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Use `ro+=1;`, simply `ro++;` (which increments it in location) or `ro=++ro;` (pointless, but perhaps you find it more readable)

Comment: The reason your current iterator isn't working is that preincrement ( `++i` ) adds one to the value of i and *then* returns i.  postincrement (  `i++` ), which is what you are doing, returns i *then* adds one to it.

Comment: _Anyone knows why?_ perhaps the conditions aren't being met and according to your code, the _ro_ variable only increment if get in one of the two conditions that you have there.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this `ro=ro++;` with this `ro++;` or this `ro=ro+1`.

Comment: @user3709132 you welcome. definetely you are not a dumb. It happens sometimes to make mistakes. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: I committed a similar mistake and I have some years on Python programming. So me too: you're not a dumb. And if you are, we are two :).